# How can i launch youtube fullscreen from terminal

Tags: python, terminal, youtube, subprocess, shlex

i am trying to get running video via terminal call to get fullscreen and good resolution, but i don't know how to set arguments.

i am on linux, i do this on terminal:

```
firefox -new-tab https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spUNpyF58BY
```

but:
1-it's not running, it's just waiting to start
2-it's not fullscreen
3-how to choose video quality
4-is it possible to set audio voume to 100%

i'd like to avoid selenium but if necessary, what should i writte?

Comment: Are you on linux or win ? if linux, `firefox.exe -new-tab  https://www.youtube.com/embed/spUNpyF58BY
xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class "Firefox" windowactivate key F11`

Comment: Volume isn't possible, here's a list of  supported parameter https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters

Comment: i am on linux, i tryed this but it does not run$                                                                 firefox -new-tab https://www.youtube.com/embed/spUNpyF58BY?autoplay=1&fs=1

Comment: install `xdotool `, then run `xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class "Firefox" windowactivate key` after `firefox.exe -new-tab https://www.youtube.com/embed/spUNpyF58BY`